# Why I cannot see quick format option when "create an encrypted file container"

Tags: truecrypt

Based on this http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=creating-new-volume
I have an option to quick format the drive.

However, when I create a volume with options of "create an encrypted file container", I don't see any way that I can choose "quick format". In the regular format procedure, I have to wait hours before it can finish the format.

Can someone know a workaround?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can start the TrueCrypt volume creation and then end the process. You will have a container that has enough setup to begin use.

> 1: Start the volume formatting. Allow it to run for a few seconds.
>
> 2: Open the Task Manager and kill off the TrueCrypt Format process.
>
> [image: Taskmanager - look for 'TrueCrypt Format.exe']
>
> 3: Mount the newly created TrueCrypt volume and format it with the OS.
>
> [image]

I am assuming that the process is named similar in OSX and Linux and the file creation and data seeding should be the same - I have not tested this under OSX or Linux.

***The container** will not be the most secure as it **has not been seeded with random data**. You can however begin using it as you have successfully bypassed the formatting.

BTW TrueCrypt is alive and well:

https://truecrypt.ch/

https://github.com/CipherShed/CipherShed/pulse/monthly